# Random mouse movements and drag times in Python

Tags: python, random

I would like to make a script that drags the mouse to a x, y in a random line every time with a random drag time everytime, when it arrives at x, y it needs to click a random location in a specified rectangle.

Ive tried reading about it but havent gotten anything to work, all help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking your problem down into simple functions. For example:

- move the mouse
- find the screen dimensions
- generate a random number between two numbers
- generate X and Y for a line between two points
- delay some ms in a loop
- click the mouse

You can then compose these to make more complicated functions. 
"click a random location in a specified rectangle" can be broken down into:

- (generate a random number between) ( -rectangle_width / 2, rectangle_width / 2)
- (generate a random number between) ( -rectangle_height / 2, rectangle_height / 2)
- calculate the new mouse position with these offsets
- (click the mouse)